# pySpark jdbc write error: An error occurred while calling o43.jdbc. : scala.MatchError: null

Tags: pyspark, db2, apache-spark-sql, spark-jdbc

I am trying to write simple spark dataframe to db2 database using pySpark. Dataframe has only one column with double as a data type.

This is the dataframe with only one row and one column:
[image: PySpark dataframe]

This is the dataframe schema:
[image: PySpark dataframe schema]

When I try to write this dataframe to db2 table with this syntax:

```
dataframe.write.mode('overwrite').jdbc(url=url, table=source, properties=prop)
```

it creates the table in the database for the first time without any issue, but if I run the code second time, it throws an exception:
[image: Error Log]

On the DB2 side the column datatype is also `DOUBLE`.

Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: @pault : but actually with mode ='overwrite' expected behavior is , if data/table already exists, existing data is expected to be overwritten by the contents of the DataFrame. In this case the PySpark dataframe schema and db2 table schema are matching so ideally overwrite should not give issue. Also mode = 'append' is not working in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed small part in the code and it worked perfectly. 
Here is the small change I did to syntax

```
dataframe.write.jdbc(url=url, table=source, mode = 'overwrite', properties=prop)
```